# Detecting sans-serif font family

Tags: sans-serif, auto-detection

I am preparing a set of macros whose behavior has to be different depending on whether the current font is bold and/or italic and/or sans-serif.

By reading the previously answered questions, I have come up with a possible solution.
However, it seems that my solution is not capable of correctly detecting whether the font family is sans-serif or not.

I list below a MWE in which I use the core part of my macros that should detect the font-family. It correctly detects whether the font is bold and/or italic, but apperently it does not correctly detect whether the font is sans-serif.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\edef\namebold{\bfdefault}
\edef\namesansserif{\sfdefault}
\edef\nameit{\itdefault}

\makeatletter
\textsf{\textbf{\textit{%
\newline
\f@series-\namebold:
\ifx\f@series\namebold%
TRUE!!!%
\else%
FALSE!!!%
\fi%
\newline
\f@family-\namesansserif:
\ifx\f@family\namesanserif%
TRUE!!!%
\else%
FALSE!!!%
\fi%
\newline
\f@shape-\nameit:
\ifx\f@shape\nameit%
TRUE!!!%
\else%
FALSE!!!%
\fi%
}}}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

This is the result that I obtain. I expect that also the second query answers true, given that "lmss" and "lmss" are the same. What is wrong with the code?

[image: The result of the MWE]

Comment: You have a typo. There is an s missing in \namesanserif.

Comment: Thank you! Wow, it was that easy. I didn't receive any compilation warning.

Comment: You were using the undefined command in an \ifx and so the test result was simply false.